# How to get Lilypond to produce a "repeat lyrics here" mark?

Tags: notation, lilypond, repeats

I'd like to get lilypond to produce the ://: mark above the stave used in hymnals (at least) to indicate "repeat the preceding line of words here" - for an example of what I mean, see [the mark above the stave in the first bar of the second page](https://hymnary.org/hymn/NEH1985/353a). Is it possible? I've spent some time looking a snippets to no avail - it doesn't appear to be a glyph I could include using \markup or anything like that...

I found a hack, which is to use the closest-approximate unicode glyph as a breath mark:

```
\override BreathingSign.text = ""
\breathe
```

Comment: The sign itself can be generated with `\repeat percent 2 { c'1 c' }`. The name of the Lilypond's internal symbol is `DoublePercentEvent`. You will find basic information here: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.21/Documentation/notation/short-repeats.html . Maybe someone knows how to use that symbol in a markup.

Comment: The difficulty is that the percent repeat isn't a single glyph in the music font (otherwise you could indeed insert it); there's a snippet to put one in the middle of the stave
https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.21/Documentation/snippets/repeats#repeats-isolated-percent-repeats
and another answer on adjusting its placement - 
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/93829/how-do-i-raise-or-lower-lilyponds-repeat-percent-symbol ...but in any case it's not really quite the right glyph

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
#(define-markup-command (repeat-text layout props) ()
   #:properties ((font-size 0))
   (let* ((dot (interpret-markup layout props (markup #:fontsize (- font-size) #:musicglyph "scripts.staccato")))
          (ddots (ly:stencil-add dot (ly:stencil-translate dot '(0.3 . 0.6))))
          (line (make-line-stencil 0.2 0 0 0.55 1.1))
          (stc (ly:stencil-add (ly:stencil-translate ddots '(-0.3 . 0.4)) line
                               (ly:stencil-translate line '(0.4 . -0.1))
                               (ly:stencil-translate ddots '(1.02 . 0)))))
     (ly:stencil-scale stc (magstep font-size) (magstep font-size))))

{ 1
  % with 2.23 the following can be done like
  % \after 2 \mark\markup\repeat-text 2.
  <<
    {s2 \mark\markup\repeat-text}
    2.
  >>
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's constructing the entire thing by hand, hardcore!

Comment: Also, alas, this doesn't seem to work - I put your define at the top of my ly and added  
"\mark\markup\repeat-text" into my music after the relevant note and get an error:  

Preprocessing graphical objects...repton.ly:7:17: In expression (make-path-stencil (quote #) 0.2 ...):
repton.ly:7:17: Unbound variable: make-path-stencil

Comment: @mcv21 May I inquire what Lilypond version you are using? In case you are prior to 2.19 the `make-path-stencil` function does not yet exists. But instead we can use `make-line-stencil`, which is also more simple in syntax in this example. I’ve changed by code to do this, please try again if it works for you. In any case if you are still on 2.18 or earlier please consider updating Lilypond. 2.18 is many years old and has received many improvements and bug fixes.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am using 2.18 (it's what comes with my distro), and your revised version does work. Though I'm afraid I conclude my unicode-related bodge is a nicer visual effect.