# Raise or lower position of percent repeat counters by voice in Lilypond?

Tags: lilypond, engraving, repeats

[There is a very similar question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/93829/how-do-i-raise-or-lower-lilyponds-repeat-percent-symbol); however, I cannot use its answer because it sets the `\override PercentRepeatCounter.Y-offset = #-3` inside the `\layout` of a `score` block.

I need the ability to leave voice 1 with its percent repeat counter in its default position while placing the counter for voice 2 below the staff.  The voices must share a stave, as this is for a condensed percussion part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to place the override in the `\layout` block, you can (and should) place it in the `\new DrumVoice` (or whichever relevant voice) block:

```
snareDrum = {
    \new DrumVoice {
        \voiceOne
        \set countPercentRepeats = ##t
        \drummode {
           sn16 16 8 16 16 8 16 16 8 16 16 8 |
            \repeat percent 3 {
                sn4 8 8 4 8 8 |
            }
        }
    }
}

bassDrum = {
    \new DrumVoice {
        \set countPercentRepeats = ##t
        \override PercentRepeatCounter.Y-offset = #-3       
        \override PercentRepeat.Y-offset = #-3
        %\override DoublePercentRepeat.Y-offset = #-3
        \voiceTwo
        \drummode {
            \repeat percent 4 {
                bd4 r4 bd4 r4 |
            }
        }
    }
}

\new DrumStaff {
    <<
        \snareDrum
        \bassDrum
    >>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for including `DoublePercentRepeat` in there as well, as 90% of the repeats in this piece I'm engraving are two-bar repeats.